# Is there any way to identify that my app is executing first time on iphone?

Tags: iphone

I want to show a message of instructions when user first time use my application, but then never until he won't delete it and re-download,,,

one easy way is to save some value in sqlite3 database and match it, 
but I want to use something else,,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do anything the other answerers suggested, or just check for a certain file (call it firstrun.txt) under app "Documents" directory to exist at startup.

If it doesn't exist, show the welcome message and create it, otherwise, do nothing. When the user updates the app, the "Documents" directory doesn't get emptied.

That's it.

Comment: i initially gave u +1... for coming up with something different and unusual bcos I could never think for creating a file when I have NSUserDefaults for that task ....  ur solution will work like charm.. but suddenly I realise what our programming teachers used to teach us .." many way of doing things, choose the optimum one", so I took back my upvote.. anyways appreciations for ur out of the box thinking...

Comment: @Iphone_bharat: You're right. I'm a (quite experienced) C programmer, and I always tend to use "old school" solutions. It's hard to me to use a specific class when I can just check a file for existence or not :)

Comment: @Iphone_bharat,,, I can do by saving simply in sqlite, but I want something else, you saying not to use NSUserDefaults, but still it is not working for me, and as far as voteup is concern, I really believe in learning, not in votes

Comment: the voteup thing was for Giacomo and not for u Veer... I think U misunderstood it.. it was in different context .. and for Ur question "NSUserDefaults" should work... and that is the best way to do what u want to achieve.. how it is not working for u.. could u post some code... what u have written .. have u followed what conmulligan has said

Comment: @Veer: NSUserDefaults will just work for you, like my solution, as well. It's up to you to choose. Byez

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [`NSUserDefaults`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kHasRun] == NO) { 

    // do something

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:kHasRun];
}
```

Comment: What is kHasRun, a user defined BOOL or something else?

Comment: Yes, `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` in your app delegate is the ideal place. `kHasRun` is just a `#define` constant; you can use an `NSString` like `@"MyStartupKey"` instead if you like.

Answer (score 0):

you ca use sqlite or plist or [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] for saving value.